# Can we recover $X$ from $K = X^T X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a real matrix $K$ which is a gram matrix of $X$, $K = X^TX$, for some unknown $X$. In this case, would $X$ be unique so that we may have a function
$$
f(K) = X?
$$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ cannot possibly be unique, because if I replace $X$ by $QX$ where $Q$ is orthogonal then I get another such factorization. However, you can choose $X$ upper triangular, in which case this is called the Cholesky factorization, and it is unique if $K$ is positive definite. (Simply knowing that there exists $X$ such that $K=X^T X$ only tells you that $K$ is positive semidefinite.)

Comment: @Royi The moral of the story of my answer is that the right analogue of "$x=\pm y$" (which is what you have in 1D) is "$A=QB$ for some orthogonal $Q$".

Comment: @Royi That's just false without an additional restriction, take $P=I$, take $A$ to be whatever full rank matrix you want, and take $B=QA$ for any orthogonal $Q$ you want. (Or I guess $AQ$ with the way you wrote it.)

Comment: @Royi Now I understand the question, but no, I don't really know about that type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the uniqueness already fails for $n=1$: $$1=1^2=(-1)^2.$$

Besides multiplying $X$ by an orthogonal matrix on the left, you can multiply it on the right by any orthogonal matrix that commutes with $K$ (if there's any, other than the identity).

Also, if the size of $X$ is not fixed, you have things like
$$
[1]=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt3\\1/\sqrt3\\1/\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt3\\1/\sqrt3\\1/\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}=\cdots
$$
and infinitely many other possible combinations.